# django.db.utils.OperationalError; filtering QuerySet with date lookup

Tags: python, django

I'm going through an example where a Model has a `DateTimeField` defined upon it. When trying to create a filtered QuerySet with a `date` lookup, the following error is returned. I'm confused as to why this error is being raised. It makes it sound like a function that I wrote is causing the error (which is not the case), but perhaps I'm reading that incorrectly.

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: user-defined function raised exception`

```
>>> a = Employee.objects.create(
  alias="User", age=0, hired=datetime(2020, 6, 12), experience=0
)
>>> result = Employee.objects.filter(hired__date__gt=datetime(2019, 1, 1))
```

```
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    alias = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=11)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    hired = models.DateTimeField()
    experience = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.alias
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be,

`result = Employee.objects.filter(hired__date__gte=datetime.date(2019, 1, 1))`

Comment: What purpose would the date lookup serve then?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#date

For datetime fields, casts the value as date. Allows chaining additional field lookups. Takes a date value.

Comment: Updated answer. if you want to use date lookup you yourself referenced to right docs. Note I added `.date` method at end. Docs refer them with date lookup, it separates and removes time from date. I hope you understand ask anything if want too I'll clear you.